# Add features to all child classes in python module

Tags: python, inheritance, metaprogramming

I'd like to update some parent class in a python module to add a feature to all children classes. The module is installed via `pip`.

If I can modify the parent class, I just add methods to it. But, I should not edit installed modules. (following my previous [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909158/manage-python-modules-repeatedly-updated-in-both-local-and-original-repository))

How can I add a feature to all children classes inside a python package without editing files inside pip package directories?

One alternative is using [monkeypatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765222/monkey-patch-python-class), but seems too tricky.

#### Update

Concrete situation is that I'd like to add common method to `Child1` and `Child2`, but can not edit Parent because it is a class of a `pip` package.

```
class Parent:
    ...

class Child1(Parent):
    ...

class Child2(Parent):
    ...
```

Comment: have you tried creating another parent class which can be inherited by Child1 and Child2?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent:
    ...

class Mixin:
    def common_method (self, ...):
        ....

class Child1 (Parent, Mixin):
    ....

class Child2 (Parent, Mixin):
    ...
```

OR

```
class Parent:
    ...

class Augmented (Parent):
    def common_method (self, ...):
        ....

class Child1 (Augmented):
    ....

class Child2 (Augmented):
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I was ambiguous. Child1 and Child2 are also inside a `pip` package. So, I can not edit Child1 and Child2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not recommending this but you could use `setattr`

```
class Parent:
    age = 50

class Child(Parent):
    age = 20

def test(cls):
    print cls.age

setattr(Parent, 'some_func', classmethod(test))

Parent.some_func()
Child.some_func()
```

This outputs

```
50
20
```

Comment: This is monkey-patching and may be the best solution. There is no difference between `setattr(Parent, 'some_func', ...)` and `Parent.some_func = ...` that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If the module doesn't rely on C code, I think monkey-patching may be the only solution short of enumerating the subclasses and manually adding the method to them.

#### test_module.py

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Child1(Parent): pass

class Child2(Parent): pass
```

#### other_file.py

```
from test_module import Parent, Child1, Child2

Parent.say = lambda self: self.name # monkey-patching

child1, child2 = Child1('Bob'), Child2('Larry')

print child1.say() # Bob
print child2.say() # Larry
```

You can even add the method to `Parent` *after* `child1` and `child2` are instantiated and still have access to it. This will also apply to new subclasses.

```
class Subchild(Child1): pass

Subchild('Moe').say() # Moe
```